# D Socket Programming Basic Connection Script

Tags: sockets, d, phobos

I am brand new to D programming so please excuse my ignorance. I am trying to create a basic program to connect to a website and download a page or connect to a restful API and download info. Right now all I need to worry about is TCP (streams). I'm using the std.socket library. Unfortunately I can't find much online or in the documentation that illustrates the proper syntax. I've done this in PHP and C++ and understand the concepts, but I could really use some help on syntax. If someone could post an example or a link it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `htmlget.d` sample that comes with your D compiler. You can see it online [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/blob/master/samples/htmlget.d).

You can find detailed documentation for the relevant standard library functions on the [D website](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_socket.html).

However, if you only need to access HTTP, it would be much simpler to use [std.net.curl](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html):

```
import std.net.curl;
string html = get("dlang.org");
```

Comment: Can't believe I couldn't find this before! Thanks for the reply. Google makes it really difficult to search for anything related to D...

Comment: Tip: when you search for anything related to D, add "dlang" to your search. Example: dlang socket

Comment: I wrote a simple webserver, not the best one. It was when I had just moved over to D almost a year ago. Not sure if it might help.

You can view the source here:
https://github.com/BaussHacker/DWebServer